# Is it acceptable to use macros for repeated code?

Tags: c++

In my code I have **dozens** of structs somewhat like these:

```
struct foo {
private:
    params _someParams;
public:
    foo(const params& p) noexcept : _someParams(p) { }
    void banana() { }
    void apple() { }
};

struct bar {
private:
    params _someParams;
public:
    foo(const params& p) noexcept : _someParams(p) { }
    void watermelon() { }
    void orange() { }
    void strawberry() { }
};
```

Is it acceptable to write a macro such as:

```
#define PARAMS_AND_CTOR(structname) \
    private: \
        params _someParams; \
    public: \
        structname(const params& p) noexcept : _someParams(p) { }
```

So I could have the structs like these?

```
struct foo {
    PARAMS_AND_CTOR(foo)
    void banana() { }
    void apple() { }
};

struct bar {
    PARAMS_AND_CTOR(bar)
    void watermelon() { }
    void orange() { }
    void strawberry() { }
};
```

Comment: Would the common parts be appropriate as a base class or a class template?  I really hate putting access specifiers in macros.  That confuses me every time.

Comment: "In my code I have dozens of structs somewhat like these:"  - why?

Comment: If the point is to save a bit of typing, it's generally not worth it. Time spent typing away is not usually significant compared to things like debugging, testing and code maintenance. In your case specifically, I'm not even sure saving a couple dozen extra lines would be worth the time it takes to write the macro. All in all, it's acceptable if you can justify it. But which aspect of your code does this macro improve? Just saving a few characters of source code is not really an improvement.

Comment: every single time I used macros merely to save typing I regretted it. There are things you cannot do within the language but you can do with macros, but when you can do it within the language, then why open a can of worms?

Comment: whether this is acceptable is just a matter of how much pain you are willing to suffer ;).

Comment: C++ gives you so many tools for code reuse. You have templates, inheritance, composition, and OOP-style design patterns. Each of this is way safer and way easier to debug and reason about than macros. Macros are the bluntest tool in the C++ toolbox and you should use them after you've ruled out every other tool.

Comment: @John That was my first try, unfortunately there are parts of the code that didn't let me do it. I wish I could show it.

Comment: FWIW, Qt uses a [bunch of macros](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#macros) for classes for their internal moc and slot magic. Some of these contain access specifiers and some contain function declarations. But then again, their documentation is rather substantial and one can still ctrl-click on the macro to see its implementation.

Comment: @TrebledJ There are ports of Qt that avoid those macros.  There are C++ features being proposed whose selling points include "get rid of those macros in Qt" (metaclasses and reflection/reification).  There are projects that jump through significant hoops to avoid having to use those macros (I've worked on more than one) or isolate Qt because of them.  So, it isn't a huge selling point.  :)

Answer (score 4):

In the general case I won't answer.  It is opinion based and/or too broad.

In this specific case, no.

```
struct base {
  params _someParams;
  base( params const& p ) noexcept:
    _someParams(p)
  {}
};  
struct foo:private base {
  using base::base;
  void banana() { }
  void apple() { }
};
```

Use this instead.

Inheriting ctors let you republish private base ctors.  Private base store your params quite nicely.

The result is debugable and has a low chance of stupid typos causing problems, as the per-struct boilerplate is simple and about as short as your macro solution.

Answer (score -1):

Acceptable is relative to your team, but I have used it in cases where the code is small and straightforward.  Consider the downsides though: You won't be able to debug line by line like normal code.  Most debuggers are not good at stepping through parts of macros.

In your scenario "PARAMS_AND_CTOR" you are getting awfully close to using macros to try and create a new language.  When you do this people now not only need to know all of C++ but your custom macros as well.  This makes the learning curve to understand your code very steep.

In extreme cases I've seen people use this to make C look like Pascal.